# Counting number of views article

Tags: python, django, view

Let's assume I've blog with articles. I'd like to count number of views my article in Django. For example: Views: 153.

How can I count number of the views?

```
def preview(request, id):
   article = Articles.objects.get(id=id)
```

Comment: Can you give more details about your `Article` model?

Answer (score 0):

A very basic way to do it would be to have:

In your `models.py` have a`view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)` in your `Article` model.

In `views.py`, you would increment `view_count` by 1 every time it is called and add
`article.view_count += 1' somewhere to keep track of how many hits the page received.

This runs into the problem of tracking whether it is the same person making the views and could easily be gamed, but it is a workable rudimentary solution.

Comment: Okay but how to detect when someone will click at my article?

Comment: When someone clicks on the article, Django goes to the particular view for that article to provide it to the person clicking. So the act of opening the page registers the increment in view_count.

Comment: Okay. I'd like when the person will click 10 times, I don't want 10 views. Can I count views throught session of user? When user will click 10 times, the views will be equal to 1 view?

Comment: You essentially would need to track whether the user had already been seen before on that page. Cookies and session could work for that purpose.